# Getting random accuracy without changing the code

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have a simple Keras Model for training `AND` logic. Unfortunately the accuracy is sometimes `0.75` or `1.0` after running my project again and again. Why the accuracy is changing without I change the `epochs` or other parameters. Why this is happening?

```
import numpy as np
import keras

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy

x_train = np.array([[1,1], [0,1], [1,0], [0,0]])
x_val = np.array([[0,1], [1,1], [1,0], [0,0]])
x_test = np.array([[0,1], [1,0], [1,1], [0,0]])


y_train = np.array([[1], [0], [0], [0]])
y_val = np.array([[0], [1], [0], [0]])
y_test = np.array([[0], [0], [1], [0]])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

opt = RMSprop(lr=0.001)
model.compile(
    optimizer=opt,
    loss=binary_crossentropy,
    metrics=['accuracy']    
)

model.summary()

model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=100, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=32)

print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

model.predict_classes(np.array([[0,1]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the (very) small size of your sample (4) and the fact that you actually don't have separate training, validation, and test sets (they are all identical), your model is not *deterministic*: there is always the random element of the weights initialization. This sometimes results to a model that can correctly predict all your (4...) training samples (accuracy 1.0), and sometimes to models that misclassify just one sample (accuracy 0.75). There is nothing strange going on here.

> Why are weights initialized randomly?

How else? It is not a good idea to initialize them to 0 (you can do this with the *bias*, but not with the weights) because then your model would be unable to learn...

You may find the following useful:

[What are good initial weights in a neural network?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47590/what-are-good-initial-weights-in-a-neural-network) (caution because it is a little old...)

[Why Initialize a Neural Network with Random Weights?](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-initialize-a-neural-network-with-random-weights/)

> I mean there is a prove that some weights at the beginning are better for the accuracy?

Not exactly; but there has been evidence that some initializing methods work better in practice. Keras layers are nowadays initialized with `glorot_uniform` (see the default `kernel_initializer` argument in the [layers documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/)). You may want to have a look and possibly experiment with the different [initializers available in Keras](https://keras.io/initializers/). This is still an area of active research...